# gnome-tweak-tools Titlebar Actions Middle-Click Toggle Maximize Vertically not working

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The `Toggle Maximize Vertically` option of tweak-tools is not working (see screenshot). With this setting on, a middle click fully maximizes some apps, vertically maximizes others, and does nothing for others.

The `Maximize window vertically` keyboard shortcut does work, however.

Is this a bug with tweak-tools? Is there a way I can set a custom action of the Middle-Click, perhaps for the keyboard shortcut I've set which I know works?

Thanks

[image: gnome-tweak-tools screenshot]